# A word that describes me being unable to understand a situation

Tags: single-word-requests

There are times when I want to apologize for not knowing the full situation. I am not sure the word is naive, but I want to say "I apologize for being naive, but I would like to make a suggestion while excusing myself for possibly missing why it is being done the way that it is."

Is there a better word to use than naive?

Comment: Consult a thesaurus: [innocent, unsophisticated, artless, ingenuous, inexperienced, guileless, unworldly, trusting, gullible, credulous, immature, callow, raw, green, wide-eyed, wet behind the ears, born yesterday](http://vocabdictionary.com/dictionary/translate/naive/naive-meaning-in-georgian-English)

Comment: "I'm relatively ignorant on this matter, but if I could venture a suggestion..."

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, you are

**uninformed** ([TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/uninformed))

> adj.
>
> not having knowledge or information about a situation, subject, etc

Just because you don't understand, doesn't mean it is necessarily solely your fault. It could be a combination of factors which make the situation, in your estimation,

**unclear** ([TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unclear))

> adj.
>
> 1. Not expressed clearly: *The host's directions to the beach house were unclear, so many guests got lost on the way.*
> 2. Confused or doubtful; not certain: *Our discussion left me unclear as to what you wanted me to do.*

Therefore, you could say "I apologize for appearing **uninformed**, but it is **unclear** why *X* is being done *Y* way. If I could make a suggestion to do *Z* instead..."

Answer (score 0):

I have heard the word "Befuddled" used in this scenario. Often to explain oneself as unable to "comprehend" or "digest" the topic at hand.

> **be·fud·dle.**  ([BING](https://www.bing.com/search?q=Befuddled&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IENTTR&conversationid=&toHttps=1&redig=A041B57F1CE14AF6A7A23B6B8ED02DC3) , [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Befuddled))
>
> VERB
>        1.make (someone) unable to think clearly:
>        *"he has an air of befuddled unworldliness*"
>        synonyms: confused · muddled · addled · bewildered · disoriented

And

> tr.v. be·fud·dled, be·fud·dling, be·fud·dles
>
> 1. To cause (someone) to be unable to think clearly; confuse:
> 2. To stupefy with alcohol; intoxicate.
>
> Synonyms:  befuddle, addle, discombobulate, fuddle, muddle

Comment: It wasn't my downvote but good answers here tend to be backed up with dictionary references.

Comment: ok, makes sense I guess, a bit like, "let me Google that for you"

Comment: I've edited your answer to use the quote tag rather than the source code one.  If you edit it and link "befuddle" to the dictionary from which you took the definition, I'm sure you'll be on your way to upvote-city. :)

Comment: Nice fix, I default to code blocks.